# centered horizontal navigation bar css

Tags: html, css

I know there are a lot of answers with this subject but it still doesn't work somehow with my code. 
Every time I try to center the text with text-align center it doesn't work unless I remove float: left, display: inline or display: inline-block. But then I have a vertical centered navigation bar...

Can anyone help me with this?

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="workshop.html">Moviekids festivals</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS code:

```
*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

body {
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
background-color: white;
}

#wrapper{
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100%;
text-align: left;
background-color: #1d1d1b;
}

.nav {
background-image:url("img/nav.jpg");
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li {
display: inline;
text-align: center;
}

.nav a {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
color: #1d1d1b;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Post your full HTML code.

Comment: And a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: basicly: ul {text-align:center;} and li {display:inline-block;} will do.

Comment: your code seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/14r9bjst/

Comment: @superUntitled untill #wrapper does not stand in the way :) http://jsfiddle.net/5fy4v10o/

Comment: @GCyrillus Add `text-align:center;` to the `.nav` http://jsfiddle.net/5fy4v10o/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the text-align on the parent element like so:

```
.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[See Demo](http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/HGEem)

Comment: Glad to hear it, based on this could you mark the answer as accepted. This question explains a bit more: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I just edited your css to acheive what you need

```
.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align:center;
}

.nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #1d1d1b;  
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/bydf9545/)

Always avoid using body text-align try using instead for wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have mentioned `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the top of your HTML code.
Otherwise your code seems perfect.